# How to get a value with argument/flag from controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, properties

I want to get the property defined in my controller. I do need a property, cause I am using it also in a template.

My Implementation:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    canNotSave: function(lookup) {
        console.log(lookup);
        if(lookup === true) {
            //.... DO SOMETHING
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }.property(),

    actions: {
        close: function() {
          var canNotSave = this.get('canNotSave',true); //<- This is not working
          if(canNotSave)
          {
            //.... DO SOMETHING
          }
        }
    },
});
```

Is this possible to do something like this? And how?

Comment: That is not how computed properties work, you cannot pass a parameter to get.

Comment: This was just an example! I do know that this won't work

Comment: Why downvote ? Some guys who are new to emberjs will not understand things like you do, so they ask questions ...

Comment: I just noticed you are using `ObjectController`, that was deprecated and removed in 2.0, what version are you using?

Comment: 1.10.0 ;-) And do not suggest to update. I am new to this project, and I already considered but working for a big firm is not that easy as you think. Also there would be a lot of refactoring....And yeah by the way .... It's hard to find working examples for an outdated technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    lookup: null,
    canNotSave: Ember.computed("lookup", function() {
        if(this.get("lookup")) {
            //.... DO SOMETHING
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }),

    actions: {
        close: function() {
          this.set("lookup", true);
          if(this.get("canNotSave")) {
            //.... DO SOMETHING
          }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try :D